# Simple service based on Observable with Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I would like to use `Rxjs` in my project which is based on `Angular 1.5` and written in `ECMA 5`. I would like to rewrite my service methods which are based on promises and want implement Observables.

I write sth like this in my service:

```
    function service(Restangular) {

    var self = this;

    self.user = new Rx.Subject();

    var service = {
        artistStream: artistStream,
    };



    function artistStream(artist) {
        self.user.onNext({
            data : Restangular
                    .all('text/')
                    .customGET('search', {q : artist})
        });
    }


    return service;
}
```

And then I tried use this service in my component like this :

```
        function testRx(artist) {

            console.log(artistService.artistStream(artist));

         }
```

I get error from console :

> TypeError: self.user.onNext is not a function

What I'm doing wrong? It is my first time when I use Observables

Answer (score 3):

Ok, rewrite service and work properly.

```
        function artistStream(artist) {

        const promise = Restangular
                    .all('text/')
                    .customGET('search', {q : artist})

        const subscription = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise);

        return subscription;

    }
```